# How to combine two foreach loops?

Tags: windows-server-2003, powershell, user-management, workgroup

I've looked at how to combine multiple commands with psexec but none of the methods seems to work. Maybe it's because I'm running the script in PowerShell and not cmd.exe?

I need to create user accounts AND add them to the local Administrators group on non-domain computers (Windows 2003). I've derive the following script (which works) but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to combine the two foreach loops as it has to establish the psexec connection twice for each server.

```
$username = Read-Host "User name:"
$password = Read-Host "Password:"
$fullname = Read-Host "Full name:"
$computers = Get-Content C:\Tools\scripts\ServerList.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    psexec \\$computer -u username -p password net user $username $password /add /fullname:""$fullname"" /comment:"Comment"
}

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    psexec \\$computer -u username -p password net localgroup Administrators $username /add
}
```

As I mentioned, this is being run in PowerShell. The servers that I'm running it on are Workgroup Windows 2003 Servers without PowerShell installed.

Comment: Are you trying to simplify your command to run one single complex command? Or are you trying to consolidate your loops?  If you wanted to consolidate your loops, since the logic is the same, just take the command from loop 2 and stick it in after the command in loop1.  If you're trying to consolidate the command into one single complex command; why?  Those are two separate functions.  You need to create a new user before you can add the user to a group.  You can't do it at the same time even in GUI.

Comment: Well if I could make it into one single command that would be preferable but what I've tried hasn't worked. I see @briantist 's answer below might work - haven't tried that way yet with the ^&^&. I wanted to avoid having to establish two psexec sessions independently.

Comment: searching for `psexec combine commands` provides numerous examples where everything you're looking to do can be consolidated into a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @CIA said, you can combine the loops by just running `psexec` twice in one loop.

```psh
$username = Read-Host "User name:"
$password = Read-Host "Password:"
$fullname = Read-Host "Full name:"
$computers = Get-Content C:\Tools\scripts\ServerList.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    psexec \\$computer -u username -p password net user $username $password /add /fullname:""$fullname"" /comment:"Comment"
    psexec \\$computer -u username -p password net localgroup Administrators     
}
```

But it seems like what you're really asking is how to run both *net commands* in a single `psexec` session.

```
$username = Read-Host "User name:"
$password = Read-Host "Password:"
$fullname = Read-Host "Full name:"
$computers = Get-Content C:\Tools\scripts\ServerList.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    psexec \\$computer -u username -p password net user $username $password ullname"" /comment:"Comment" ^&^& net localgroup Administrators     
}
```

You can try it this way, but I'm not sure it will work. The `&&` is escaped using `^` so that it gets passed to `psexec` instead of being interpreted locally, which would have then run the second `net` command locally.

## Alternative

What you could do instead is not use `psexec` at all and use PowerShell remoting. It just has to be enabled on each machine you want to remote into. I realize this might be a bit of an undertaking, but it will be worth it since it's way more versatile, and basically, it's the future.

If you're in a domain, you can even [use Group Policy to enable PowerShell remoting](http://www.briantist.com/how-to/powershell-remoting-group-policy/) (full disclosure: this is my article).

If you did that, your code would look like this:

```
$username = Read-Host "User name:"
$password = Read-Host "Password:"
$fullname = Read-Host "Full name:"
$computers = Get-Content C:\Tools\scripts\ServerList.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ArgumentList $username,$password,$fullname -ScriptBlock { param($u,$p,$f)
        # Everything in here is executed on the remote computer
        net user $u $p /add /fullname:""$f"" /comment:"Comment"
        net localgroup Administrators     
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, my question is a little misleading. I've tried different methods of joining the commands but haven't seen ^&^& before. I'll give it a try. But if that doesn't work I'm not sure if putting both psexec commands in the same foreach will accomplish anything different than how I have it now? Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Nope - _The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string._ I tried making it `^"&"^"&"` but the net command didn't like that. Oh well, no big deal. I'll just put them both in the same loop so it looks nicer.

Comment: The carets should be in the quotes too `"^&^&"`

Comment: I see how it is. :P steal my answer and get credit for it.

Comment: @CIA heh well neither of us really gave him what he wanted (a single `psexec` call). I was really hoping the ampersands would work; maybe they will if he tries quoting them like in my last comment. You could always post an answer, he can still change his accept!

Comment: Ahh I wanted to give you credit @CIA but you had a comment and briantist had an answer. But it was all you! Don't think I'm ungrateful :-p I just tested the quoting solution but the net command didn't like that. No big deal. It does what I wanted it to do (just not as efficiently as I'd like). Thanks to you both!

Comment: @MarcLaf I just added a section with an alternative (PSRemoting) you should seriously consider for the future. Sorry the other way didn't work out.

Comment: It's alright.  I usually discuss options in comments to make sure the answer is what the user wants, then I submit a formal answer after everything works out.  Also, there is a theoretical way @MarcLaf could do it in one line, by running an elevated `cmd` prompt using `psexec -c -f\\$computer /c cmd1 && cmd2` I haven't used it before, but in theory, it launches a command prompt inside `psexec` and executes the commands of `cmd1` and `cmd2`, provided he writes out each function/parameter properly or writes a subroutine for those commands.  I don't recommend doing it this way, 'cuz reasons.

Comment: @briantist Thanks I did look into PSRemote but these systems that I'm running the script against don't have PS installed and rebooting them is a bit of a pain (users...). For future servers that require this kind of maintenance I'll definitely look at it (but it's rare that we work with non-domain joined systems).

Comment: @CIA launching an elevated prompt on the remote end is an idea but I think that's getting a bit too much for what I need to do. The resolution that you and briantist provided will be great. Thanks for your help.